# Can RTK Query be used without ever using toolkit slices, actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have been using redux-toolkit for a while now and I'm pretty satisfied with it. Now that RTK Query is popping off, I'm kinda torn right now. I'm pretty proficient with toolkit so my question is how much of a difference does it make, performance-wise, if I use RTK query only and is it even possible to use RTK Query only without writing any Slices and Reducers?

For things like authentication you must have a reducer state, right? Or is it possible with RTK'Q only? Sometimes, I use to edit table row data which reflect directly on toolkit slice state with reducer actions. Is it possible in RTK Query too?

Comment: with RTK query pretty much every change in the data which you provide by requesting an Api you did not need to have slice or  reducers.
but for little things that dose not depend on REST API you may need one.

Answer (score 0):

RTK Query really just reflects your "server state".
If you have local client state, you would use that side-by-side with a normal Redux slice.

That said, something like a form should probably only be local component state until the user decides to send the data back to the server.

If you want so, you *can* work with only RTK Query and without a single slice, even with authentication. In that case, the authentication would have to be stored in a cookie and not in the Redux store, which is a security best practice anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the RTK ApiProvider (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/ApiProvider) instead of the redux Provider.
No need for redux/store in this case - only RTK.